# Domain Host cant connect to the server filezilla

Tags: php, wordpress, server, filesystems, filezilla

can I use Filezilla to upload files to my free WordPress domain website or should the domain be not-free to do this also does the free domain from WordPress comes with a password to type in the password field in Filezilla?

also, I don't know what to type in the password field in Filezilla I don't know which password does it mean?

**sorry** :frowning: I'm a beginner in this field and I don't know much

Comment: You can use Filezilla to transfer files to a ftp server (or similar). Whether that is possible in your case depends on what kind of account you have. We cannot tell you. You will need to look into the information the service provider gave to you.

Comment: can you explain more please ? because as i said im completely begginer in this servers topic

Comment: I am sure that your service provider offers some "getting started" document. Some examples about how you can transfer content into your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the free wordpress.com account. SFTP is not available for free plan. WordPress.com Business and eCommerce plans have the feature.
More details here : https://wordpress.com/support/sftp/

Comment: now i do understand so icant transfer files without going through the business plan or eCommerce plan

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, so to upload via FTP/SFTP you will need to set up credentials with your host ie. goDaddy.

Once you have them set up you will have something that looks like this:

Host:
Username:
Password:
Port:

Put these into FileZilla which will point you to the webspace of your contract.

Comment: yeah that explains that a bit so free cant have password

Comment: Yes you have a password if you don't have credentials you will need to set this up